# Package run on SQL Server Job Agent - Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, sql-server-2012

I created a package on my SQL Server (2012) through the import/export data wizard which exports data to another SQL Server (2008).

I set up a job which runs this package but I get an error:

> Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state."

I found suggestions to set the Protection Level to "DontSaveSensitive", but after running it again on the job, I get this new error:

> "Login failed for user '*username*'.".

Note, running it on it's own / manually, it works fine. It is only failing on the job.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was a permissions issue. I changed the user account of sql server agent to Admin and it worked.

However, as I learned, [this is a bad security practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025664/access-denied-when-running-exe-with-sql-server-job-agent/14025770#comment19388522_14025770), so I'd appreciate if there are other ideas out there to get around this.